# Xamarin Open Bidding Issues

Tags: xamarin

I'm hoping somebody has wrestled with this issue and can help me out of the morass.  My app is up and running in Google Play, Samsung, Amazon and the Apple App Store and properly serving ads in every one except Amazon.  However, despite the presence of several ad sources in my mediation group only Admob seems to be serving ads and it almost looks as if the mediation group is being bypassed and only Admob is working.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!
[enter image description here][1]

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  Your post doesn't really include any useful information that we could use to help you.  You also only have it tagged with Xamarin, which doesn't really seem relevant if the problem is specifically about serving ads on a single platform.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did include several tags like "Open bidding" and "mediation" but my score was insufficient for this privilege.  I also included some screenshots but they were disallowed.  The problem is that I have a mediation group set up for open bidding that is serving ads but only from Admob and according to the instructions I've followed I should be seeing action from all the ad sources.  Kudos to Stack Overflow for a response from a DNA based life form!  That's a lot more than I'm able to get from Admob.